# How many steps does Euclid's algorithm take with two polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity, euclidean-algorithm

Say we have two polynomials, $a(x)$ of degree $n$ and $b(x)$ of degree $m$, where $n > m$. Euclid's algorithm lets us compute the GCD of these two polynomials using Euclidean division (detailed at: [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclid.27s_algorithm)).

What is the maximum number of steps / Euclidean divisions that Euclid's algorithm will need to get the GCD? Is it logarithmic in the degree, similar to Euclid's algorithm for the integers? Or is it linear in the degree (please provide a sample $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ if so).

Comment: You can guarantee to reduce the degree only by $1$ at each stage. You can work the algorithm backwards to find examples.

Comment: Observe that the degree of a polynomial is at par with the number of bits of an integer. So the computational complexities are in the same class. This is very clear in the case of polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_2$. Over a larger field, like $\Bbb{Q}$, the complexity gets a factor from needing to do more complicated arithmetical operations with individual elements of the field. So the Euclidean algortihm in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ has complexity that depends (polynomially) on the degrees of the polynomials as well as on the size of the coefficients.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So in terms of the question posed, the degree of the polynomial is akin to the logarithm of an integer.

Comment: @MarkBennet That's the main point. But I did notice that I ignored the complexity of arithmetical operations with the coefficients. I edited the comment to reflect that. My knee-jerk thinking came from studying a bit much of number theory in polynomial rings $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$.